# Bash : Concatenate wildcard to a variable in a for loop

Tags: bash, glob

Don't be to hard on me this is my first bash attempt since school (like 9 years ago).

I'm trying to create a script that will rsync remote git repos locally.

I want to store my local directory into a variable because I'm using it several times but I don't find how to do it with the wildcard I use in the for loop.

I tried to concatenate the "/*/" and some other things that I didn't really understood but nothing worked.

Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage :"
    echo "syncDown <repo1> <repo2> ..."
    echo "syncDown --all"
    exit 1;
fi

LOCAL_PATH="/Volumes/Case Sensitive/repos"

# Sync all local repos
if [ $1 = "--all" ]; then
    # for dir in "$LOCAL_PATH/*/";do <-- What I tried
    for dir in /Volumes/Case\ Sensitive/repos/*/;do # <-- What works
        folder=$(echo $dir | rev | cut -d'/' -f2 | rev);
        rsync -avzh --delete-after devweb:$folder --exclude ".git" --exclude ".idea" "$LOCAL_PATH"
    done
# Sync specific repos
else
    for repo in "$@"; do
        rsync -avzh --delete-after devweb:$repo --exclude ".git" --exclude ".idea" "$LOCAL_PATH"
    done
fi
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using:

```
for dir in "$LOCAL_PATH"/*/; do
```

Make sure to not keep glob character in quote and quote only the variable.

Comment: You should also quote `"$dir"` where you are using it inside the loop.